# CocoaAsyncSocket: Error creating iOS UDP socket when dispatch_sync(socketQueue, block) is called

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, udp, cocoaasyncsocket

I would like to write an **iOS Swift app** that connects to an UDP server locally.

Here is the code I wrote using a library called **CocoaAsyncSocket**, however when I run it it does crash.

I haven't found any similar high level API in Apple. The only thing I found is this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/CH73-SW2) which suggest to us a higher level API.

Would you be able to point me towards a better library or towards resolving the bug I get?

```
import UIKit
import CocoaAsyncSocket

class OutputSocket: NSObject, GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate {

    var serverIP = "127.0.0.1"
    var port:UInt16 = 10000
    var socket:GCDAsyncUdpSocket!

    override init(){
        super.init()
        setupConnection()
    }

    func setupConnection(){
        socket = GCDAsyncUdpSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)

        do {
            try socket.bind(toPort: self.port)
        }
        catch {
             print("binding error: ", error.localizedDescription)
        }

        let addressData = serverIP.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        do {
            try socket.connect(toAddress: addressData!)}
        catch
        {
            print("connecting error: ", error.localizedDescription)
        }

        do {
            try socket.beginReceiving()
        }
        catch {
            print("connecting error: ", error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func send(message:String){
        let data = message.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let addressData = serverIP.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        socket.send(data!, toAddress: addressData!, withTimeout: 2, tag: 0)
    }

    func udpSocket(_ sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didConnectToAddress address: Data) {
        print("didConnectToAddress");
    }

    func udpSocket(_ sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didNotConnect error: Error?) {
        print("didNotConnect \(error)")
    }

    func udpSocket(_ sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didSendDataWithTag tag: Int) {
        print("didSendDataWithTag")
    }

    func udpSocket(_ sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket!, didNotSendDataWithTag tag: Int, dueToError error: Error!) {
        print("didNotSendDataWithTag")
    }
}
```

---

**Error description:**

When I run it it crashes here:

[image]

EDIT:

I have removed the IP address from the equation and now, when  I run the following code I get "didNotSendDataWithTag":

```
    let data = message.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    socket.send(data!, withTimeout: 2, tag: 0)
```

Any idea why?

Comment: I use the same library for communicating via UDP sockets. I do not connect to the IP address. I bind to the port and then start sending and receiving. The library examples don't use the connect method either. They bind to the port and begin receiving. Try taking that part out.

Comment: I removed that but the app does not seem to be able to send it. I have got a local server running in python waiting for a message. When I run the following code I get this error "didNotSendDataWithTag" - updating answer

Comment: The way I have mine setup is to broadcast across the UPD port. All devices will be able to see the message. I had to socket.enableBroadcast(true) and send to the host 255.255.255.255 because I don't know the destination IP at the time using send:toHost:port:withTimeout:tag:

Comment: ok. Thanks. I managed to send to the right server. The only issue is that now, when the server is broadcasting, I am unable to receive the data. The server is at a specific address which I know.